# Saving H264 RTP Packets In Useful Form

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, h.264, rtp, rtsp-client

I know that it is possible to save RTP h264 streams using Wireshark and VLC. But in order to learn more about video streaming I am trying to do it myself.  There are several related questions that make for good reading on this topic:

[How to process raw UDP packets so that they can be decoded by a decoder filter in a directshow source filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i)

[Problem to Decode H264 video over RTP with ffmpeg (libavcodec)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493742/problem-to-decode-h264-video-over-rtp-with-ffmpeg-libavcodec)

[How to convert H.264 UDP packets to playable media stream or file (defragmentation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404047/how-to-convert-h-264-udp-packets-to-playable-media-stream-or-file-defragmentati)

With those as background, this is where I am currently:

- I can receive RTP packets over UTP.
- I parse packets as discussed in the questions above.
- I write the packets to a file, separated by \x000001 and add the NAL byte again according to the above guides.
- At the beginning of the file I put the SPS and PPS which I got from my code's RTSP conversation with the server (again seperated by the correct bytes).

I end up with a file of supposedly a lot of NAL frames.  I then try to run ffmpeg on the .264 file to create a .mp4.  This brings up several errors:

[h264 @ 0x15257a0] decode_slice_header error

[h264 @ 0x15257a0] no frame!

[h264 @ 0x15257a0] non-existing PPS referenced

[h264 @ 0x15257a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced

[buffer @ 0x15e16a0] Invalid pixel format string '-1'

I am essentially at a standstill until I can figure out this problem.  I have thouroughly read the questions I linked to above, and the stream is definitely viewable because I can connect and watch it via VLC and the incoming packets are definitely H264 RTP packets according to wireshark.  If VLC can do it why can't I! I would greatly appreciate any insight into my errors and possible a summary of the three linked questions that resolves the disagreements between them.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to process raw UDP packets so that they can be decoded by a decoder filter in a directshow source filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i/26937003#26937003)

It has the answer you require but the process is something like this:

```
//Determine if the forbidden bit is set and the type of nal from the first byte
            byte firstByte = packetData[offset];

            //bool forbiddenZeroBit = ((firstByte & 0x80) >> 7) != 0;

            byte nalUnitType = (byte)(firstByte & Common.Binary.FiveBitMaxValue);

            //o  The F bit MUST be cleared if all F bits of the aggregated NAL units are zero; otherwise, it MUST be set.
            //if (forbiddenZeroBit && nalUnitType <= 23 && nalUnitType > 29) throw new InvalidOperationException("Forbidden Zero Bit is Set.");

            //Determine what to do
            switch (nalUnitType)
            {
                //Reserved - Ignore
                case 0:
                case 30:
                case 31:
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                case 24: //STAP - A
                case 25: //STAP - B
                case 26: //MTAP - 16
                case 27: //MTAP - 24
                    {
                        //Move to Nal Data
                        ++offset;

                        //Todo Determine if need to Order by DON first.
                        //EAT DON for ALL BUT STAP - A
                        if (nalUnitType != 24) offset += 2;

                        //Consume the rest of the data from the packet
                        while (offset < count)
                        {
                            //Determine the nal unit size which does not include the nal header
                            int tmp_nal_size = Common.Binary.Read16(packetData, offset, BitConverter.IsLittleEndian);
                            offset += 2;

                            //If the nal had data then write it
                            if (tmp_nal_size > 0)
                            {
                                //For DOND and TSOFFSET
                                switch (nalUnitType)
                                {
                                    case 25:// MTAP - 16
                                        {
                                            //SKIP DOND and TSOFFSET
                                            offset += 3;
                                            goto default;
                                        }
                                    case 26:// MTAP - 24
                                        {
                                            //SKIP DOND and TSOFFSET
                                            offset += 4;
                                            goto default;
                                        }
                                    default:
                                        {
                                            //Read the nal header but don't move the offset
                                            byte nalHeader = (byte)(packetData[offset] & Common.Binary.FiveBitMaxValue);

                                            if (nalHeader > 5)
                                            {
                                                if (nalHeader == 6)
                                                {
                                                    Buffer.WriteByte(0);
                                                    containsSei = true;
                                                }
                                                else if (nalHeader == 7)
                                                {
                                                    Buffer.WriteByte(0);
                                                    containsPps = true;
                                                }
                                                else if (nalHeader == 8)
                                                {
                                                    Buffer.WriteByte(0);
                                                    containsSps = true;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            if (nalHeader == 1) containsSlice = true;

                                            if (nalHeader == 5) isIdr = true;

                                            //Done reading
                                            break;
                                        }
                                }

                                //Write the start code
                                Buffer.Write(NalStart, 0, 3);

                                //Write the nal header and data
                                Buffer.Write(packetData, offset, tmp_nal_size);

                                //Move the offset past the nal
                                offset += tmp_nal_size;
                            }
                        }

                        return;
                    }
                case 28: //FU - A
                case 29: //FU - B
                    {
                        /*
                         Informative note: When an FU-A occurs in interleaved mode, it
                         always follows an FU-B, which sets its DON.
                         * Informative note: If a transmitter wants to encapsulate a single
                          NAL unit per packet and transmit packets out of their decoding
                          order, STAP-B packet type can be used.
                         */
                        //Need 2 bytes
                        if (count > 2)
                        {
                            //Read the Header
                            byte FUHeader = packetData[++offset];

                            bool Start = ((FUHeader & 0x80) >> 7) > 0;

                            //bool End = ((FUHeader & 0x40) >> 6) > 0;

                            //bool Receiver = (FUHeader & 0x20) != 0;

                            //if (Receiver) throw new InvalidOperationException("Receiver Bit Set");

                            //Move to data
                            ++offset;

                            //Todo Determine if need to Order by DON first.
                            //DON Present in FU - B
                            if (nalUnitType == 29) offset += 2;

                            //Determine the fragment size
                            int fragment_size = count - offset;

                            //If the size was valid
                            if (fragment_size > 0)
                            {
                                //If the start bit was set
                                if (Start)
                                {
                                    //Reconstruct the nal header
                                    //Use the first 3 bits of the first byte and last 5 bites of the FU Header
                                    byte nalHeader = (byte)((firstByte & 0xE0) | (FUHeader & Common.Binary.FiveBitMaxValue));

                                    //Could have been SPS / PPS / SEI
                                    if (nalHeader > 5)
                                    {
                                        if (nalHeader == 6)
                                        {
                                            Buffer.WriteByte(0);
                                            containsSei = true;
                                        }
                                        else if (nalHeader == 7)
                                        {
                                            Buffer.WriteByte(0);
                                            containsPps = true;
                                        }
                                        else if (nalHeader == 8)
                                        {
                                            Buffer.WriteByte(0);
                                            containsSps = true;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if (nalHeader == 1) containsSlice = true;

                                    if (nalHeader == 5) isIdr = true;

                                    //Write the start code
                                    Buffer.Write(NalStart, 0, 3);

                                    //Write the re-construced header
                                    Buffer.WriteByte(nalHeader);
                                }

                                //Write the data of the fragment.
                                Buffer.Write(packetData, offset, fragment_size);
                            }
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        // 6 SEI, 7 and 8 are SPS and PPS
                        if (nalUnitType > 5)
                        {
                            if (nalUnitType == 6)
                            {
                                Buffer.WriteByte(0);
                                containsSei = true;
                            }
                            else if (nalUnitType == 7)
                            {
                                Buffer.WriteByte(0);
                                containsPps = true;
                            }
                            else if (nalUnitType == 8)
                            {
                                Buffer.WriteByte(0);
                                containsSps = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (nalUnitType == 1) containsSlice = true;

                        if (nalUnitType == 5) isIdr = true;

                        //Write the start code
                        Buffer.Write(NalStart, 0, 3);

                        //Write the nal heaer and data data
                        Buffer.Write(packetData, offset, count - offset);

                        return;
                    }
```